# iphone tcp connection - more than one socket is being created

Tags: iphone, objective-c

i tried to create tcp connection as per this link 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server

My colleague who is writing the server part, says i get connected when i run the client. when i click the join button i open a connection and send the initial message through that but simultaneously opens another socket. 
Then onwards i receive all messages from the first connection continuously and i when i send messages it goes through the second connection.
My doubts are
1) why are 2 connections/sockets getting created here? 
2)Why am i not able to read and write through the same connection?
3)does this mean that if there are 300 client users 600 connections will be open?

I am a beginner in iphone programming. So please forgive if i am not clear.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize txtUsername,txtPassword,webData,responseString,sessionId;
@synthesize inputStream, outputStream,messages;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSLog(@"Entered main");
    [self initNetworkCommunication];
    messages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}


- (IBAction)usernExit:(id)sender {
    [txtUsername resignFirstResponder];
}

- (IBAction)pwdExit:(id)sender {
    [txtPassword resignFirstResponder];

}

- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender {

    NSLog(@"Clicked button1");

    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PMS|Login|user1|sssss"];

NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];

}

- (void) initNetworkCommunication {
    NSLog(@"initNetworkCommunication called");

CFReadStreamRef readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(NULL, (CFStringRef)@"xxx.xxx.xx.xx", xxxx, &readStream, &writeStream);
inputStream = (NSInputStream *)readStream;
outputStream = (NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
[inputStream setDelegate:self];
[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream open];
[outputStream open];
}
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"sendMessage called");

    NSString *response  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"PMS|Msg"];
NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:[response dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding]];
[outputStream write:[data bytes] maxLength:[data length]];




}

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {

NSLog(@"stream event %i", streamEvent);
switch (streamEvent) {
case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted:
NSLog(@"Stream opened");
break;
case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:

if (theStream == inputStream) {
uint8_t buffer[1024];
int len;
while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
if (len > 0) {
NSString *output = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:buffer length:len encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

if (nil != output) {

NSLog(@"server said: %@", output);
[self messageReceived:output];
}
}
}
}
break;

case NSStreamEventErrorOccurred:
NSLog(@"Can not connect to the host!");
break;
case NSStreamEventEndEncountered:
            NSLog(@"NSStreamEventEndEncountered:method is called");
            [theStream close];
            NSLog(@"theStream is closed");

            [theStream removeFromRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
            NSLog(@"theStream is removed from runloop");

            [theStream release];
            NSLog(@"theStream is released");

            theStream = nil;
break;
default:
NSLog(@"Unknown event");
}

}//End of stream
- (void) messageReceived:(NSString *)message {
    NSLog(@"Entered MessageRecieved");
[messages addObject:message];

}


- (void)dealloc {

[messages release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

.h file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <NSStreamDelegate>

@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtUsername;
@property (retain, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *txtPassword;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableData *webData;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *responseString;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSString *sessionId;


@property (retain, nonatomic) NSInputStream *inputStream;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSOutputStream *outputStream;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *messages;

- (IBAction)usernExit:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)pwdExit:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender;
- (void)initNetworkCommunication;
- (IBAction)sendMessage:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)sendMsgAgain:(id)sender;

@end
```

> ```
> the logs
> ------------------
> When i run the program
> -----------------------------
> 2013-04-29 03:57:57.826 TestConnection[13670:11303] Entered main
> 2013-04-29 03:57:57.827 TestConnection[13670:11303] initNetworkCommunication called
> 2013-04-29 03:57:57.846 TestConnection[13670:11303] stream event 1
> 2013-04-29 03:57:57.847 TestConnection[13670:11303] Stream opened
> 2013-04-29 03:57:57.847 TestConnection[13670:11303] stream event 1
> 2013-04-29 03:57:57.847 TestConnection[13670:11303] Stream opened
> 2013-04-29 03:57:57.847 TestConnection[13670:11303] stream event 4
> 2013-04-29 03:57:57.847 TestConnection[13670:11303] Unknown event
>
> When i click the first button
> ------------------------------------
> 2013-04-29 03:58:17.994 TestConnection[13670:11303] Clicked button1
> 2013-04-29 03:58:17.997 TestConnection[13670:11303] Entered main
> 2013-04-29 03:58:17.998 TestConnection[13670:11303] initNetworkCommunication called
> 2013-04-29 03:58:17.999 TestConnection[13670:11303] stream event 4
> 2013-04-29 03:58:17.999 TestConnection[13670:11303] Unknown event
> 2013-04-29 03:58:18.005 TestConnection[13670:11303] stream event 1
> 2013-04-29 03:58:18.005 TestConnection[13670:11303] Stream opened
> 2013-04-29 03:58:18.005 TestConnection[13670:11303] stream event 1
> 2013-04-29 03:58:18.005 TestConnection[13670:11303] Stream opened
> 2013-04-29 03:58:18.005 TestConnection[13670:11303] stream event 4
> 2013-04-29 03:58:18.006 TestConnection[13670:11303] Unknown event
> 2013-04-29 03:58:18.122 TestConnection[13670:11303] stream event 2
> 2013-04-29 03:58:18.123 TestConnection[13670:11303] New String JSESSIONID=56be3c2f6bbb30a6a8d0728dc710
> 2013-04-29 03:58:18.123 TestConnection[13670:11303] server said: JSESSIONID=56be3c2f6bbb30a6a8d0728dc710
> WebLoginReplyType_t.Accepted
> 2013-04-29 03:58:18.124 TestConnection[13670:11303] Entered MessageRecieved
> ```

Comment: You need to post the code indicating what you are doing in order for us to figure out what's going on.   From your description, it sounds like you're triggering multiple opens in some fashion, which would result in multiple connections.

Comment: added the respective code.sorry abt that

Comment: There doesn't appear to be anything obviously wrong there.  What are you seeing in the log?

Comment: 1) when i run the program i can see one connection(lets say CON1) established at the server side
2) when i click the first button with the message "PMS|Login|user1|sssss" another connection(lets say CON2) gets established. the server recieves this msg thru the CON1.
3)Herafter all messages sent by server are thru CON1 and all messages recieved by server are through CON2.
There are no errors or problems.
But i dont understand y are there 2 connections.Does it have something to do with each streams(outputstream and inputstream)?

Comment: Unless you're seeing `Entered Main` in your logs multiple time (hence my asking for you to put the log data up), it doesn't look like you are opening two connections.   Are you certain it's actually happening?

Comment: yes gaige.. it shows Entered Main twice..first when i run the program ..second when i click on the first button..i tried placing the [self initNetworkCommunication]; in the - (IBAction)btnLogin:(id)sender{} and it opened only one connection..but whatever client then tried sending to server was not received at server side..i have updated the post with the logs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your logs indicate that you are either getting two `viewDidLoad` messages or you are getting getting one each on two different views.  You don't mention changing view at all, so that would seem to rule out the latter, which leaves the former.

Try placing a breakpoint in `viewDidLoad` and see whether the ViewController instance (self) is the same both times. If it is the same, you'll need to look at the stack crawl and see where the second call is coming from, because hat would usually indicate a reload after a low memory event, which shouldn't happen on modern devices.  If the ViewController instance is different, then you need to see why a second ViewController is being allocated.  Again, the stack trace could help as well as creating an init method and setting a breakpoint on it.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur reply.it helped me think :) even though i am not programatically calling another view i am proceeding to a different view controller thru the xib using storyboard. i removed the segue and then it stopped opening a second connection.

Answer (score -1):

Not a real answer for your Problem, but why not just using [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket)?

This Framework provides a stable Socket you can easily use. It will create just one Socket and has many more features and many failures one can do with sockets like yours are already fixed ;)

Comment: Really irrelevant to the problem.   And in this case, it wouldn't solve the problem at all.